# Jasmine complaining that ".then is not a function" on a function that returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am testing a function to see if it is calling a function that returns a promise:

The function:

```
saveNew: (collection, query) ->
  @newId
  .then (id) ->
    $http.post server + "/api/v1/saveJson/#{collection}/#{id}", query
```

The newId function:

```
newId: () -> $http.get server + "/api/v1/newid"
```

The test:

```
describe "saveNew", () ->
    it "should call to get a new id", () ->
       spyOn(mySvc,"newId")
       entitySvc.saveNew "myCollection", {data: "stuff"}
       expect(entitySvc.newId).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

This results in

```
TypeError: this.newId.then is not a function
```

Meanwhile, I test another method that calls a function that returns a promise, and it passes:

```
findOne: (collection, query) -> @find collection, query
```

The async function:

```
find: (collection, query) -> 
    $http.post server + "/api/v1/findJson/#{collection}", query
```

The test:

```
describe "#findOne", () ->
    it "should call #find", () ->
      query = {id:1}
      collection = "myCollection"
      spyOn(mySvc,"find")
      mySvc.findOne collection, query
      expect(mySvc.find).toHaveBeenCalledWith(collection,query)
```

Comment: From what I remember `spyOn` replaces the original function with a jasmine function, and since this function doesn't return a `promise` the error occurs. To solve this try `spyOn(...).and.callThrough()` to get the original function invoked.

Comment: This seems to have made progress, but now the spied function is executing, but it has nothing to provide to the deferred .then. This doesn't seem right, I just want to test if the async newId method was called. How can I supply it with data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can spyOn with a fake call. This allows you to return out data you want through a promise.

```js
spyOn(mySvc, 'newId').andCallFake(function () {
  return $.Deferred().resolve(1);
});
```

Then you could verify that the newId returned is what you are expecting

Comment: When you want to get a fulfilled promise, it's enough to call `$q.when()`, it doesn't save the world, but it's cleaner.